# Poor rendering of graphics with Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

The following code shows the third mode shape of a circular membrane.The rendering is extemely poor as the amplitue varies. Any suggestions on how to improve performance ?

```
 Manipulate[RevolutionPlot3D[a BesselJ[0,8.65373] r], {r, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Third Mode", PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {a, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Increase the values for [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and/or [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 RevolutionPlot3D[a BesselJ[0, 8.65373 r], {r, 0, 1},
  PlotLabel -> "Third Mode",
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 2,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {{a, -1}, -1, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

[image]